# Calling TimeZone Then Running Search With It

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone

I have a user select a timezone. I then need to get the timezone that they have selected and have it passed through a search not the timezone the computer is using.

I know that:

```
.getTimezoneOffset //returns the computers offset
```

I need to get the timezone that the user has chosen as his or her timezone and pass it through the search.

My code looks like this

```
var expireFrom = $('input[name=expireFrom]').datepicker('getDate');
    var expireDate = new Date();

    if(expireFrom!=null)
            expireFrom=expireDate.getTimezoneOffset();
```

How do I call the users chosen timezone and not the computers?

Comment: How do you intend to choose a timezone offset via a datepicker? Doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

- The Javascript `Date` object is not capable of working with other time zones directly.
- [Time Zone != Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)
- Date pickers don't typically have time zone selection.  If you have one that does, you need to tell what you're using.
- If you really want to let your users pick a time zone, you'll need a control [like this one](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).
- To do anything useful with time zones, you'll need a TZDB implementation.  You are best doing this in your back-end server-side code.  If you *must* do it in JavaScript, you can try one of the libraries mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).